# Regarding expansion of the Universe and effect on the visible Universe

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, universe, space-expansion

Does the faster than light expansion of the Universe have the following consequence:
The extent of our visible universe increasing by 1 light-day every day, but due to expansion the actual contents of this visible universe will be pushed out in the future.
Does this mean we would only be able to see newly formed stars and a few nearby galaxies in the future?

Comment: General relativity does not have a natural concept of the velocity of one object relative to a distant object. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/400457/what-does-general-relativity-say-about-the-relative-velocities-of-objects-that-a . This is a notion that is either presented uncritically in popularizations or defined in certain specialized ways by people who understand the limitations of the definitions and the narrowness of their interpretation. If you like, you can say that the galaxies are *not* moving, and space is just expanding.

Comment: Well yes but it will take very long time to something like that to be happen. Like very very long. But eventually all the galaxies will be redshifted and only nearby ones will remain which they are gravitationally bounded to each other