Why does the correlation between recessional velocity derived from redshift diverge from the velocity obtained via Hubble's Law at high redshifts?
If we take Hubble's constant to be $67.5 \  \dfrac{\text{km/s}}{\text{Mpc}}$, an object at a distance of approximately $4,441.37 \ \text{Mpc}$ (megaparsecs) will be moving at approximately the speed of light. This means that objects beyond this distance will have a recessional velocity greater than the speed of light.
$$67.5 \  \frac{\text{km/s}}{\text{Mpc}} \times 4,441.37 \ \text{Mpc} = 299,792.475 \ \text{km/s} \ .$$
However, the equation used to determine an object's recessional velocity from redshift asymptotically approaches the speed of light but never exceeds it.
$$ v = c \times \frac{(z + 1)^2 - 1}{(z + 1)^2 + 1}, $$
where: $v$ is the recessional velocity,
$z$ is the redshift, and
$c$ is the speed of light.
My question is: how can objects move faster than the speed of light according to Hubble's Law, yet their recessional velocities cannot be calculated using their redshift?
To put it another way: why does the correlation between recessional velocity derived from redshift diverge from the velocity obtained via Hubble's Law for objects at high redshift or extreme distances, and at what redshift does this divergence begin to occur?

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/400457/200218

Hubble's law is the relationship between proper distance and rate of change of proper distance. Rate of change of proper distance is not the velocity implied by a special relativistic Doppler shift formula.
The "Hubble constant" is not constant in time. It is actually getting smaller and was larger in the past.

Agreed. However, the recessional velocity derived from redshift is due to the amount of space that has expanded since the light left its source until it was received. Which is the same mechanism (the expansion of space) that occurs to produce the recessional velocity derived from Hubble's Law. So given that these two separate methods use the same mechanism, where Hubble's law can derive pseudo-recessional velocities greater than the speed of light. Then it stands to reason you should be able to calculate those same higher than the speed of light velocities using only redshift.

@Tivity you can of course calculate the recession velocities (rate of change of proper distance) from redshift, but not using the SR Doppler formula, which cannot exceed $c$. The relationship must depend on the other cosmological parameters, not just $H_0$.

what's interesting is using the formula for Doppler shift against the CMB, if I multiply the speed of light by the amount of redshift of the CMB it gives me the correct temperature of the CMB at that redshift ~ $((299792458 + (1099.725*299792458))/(299792458))2.72548 =3000$. Doesn't that mean that an object at a redshift of 1099.725 will appear to be receding at $(1099.725299792458) = 329,771,703,800   m/s$?

@Tivity of course $T_{cmb} \simeq 3000/(1+z)$. And putting in $\sim c$ into Hubble's law does not give the proper distance to the CMB.
